Await js.InvokeVoidAsync("openWindowWithContent", htmlContent) throws exception
I'm using blazor server side and core.
On my razor page I have this code in the "code" section.
enter image description here
I have a code behind file that contains:
enter image description here
I have a code behind file that contains:
I use this same code in other projects and they run without fail. When I call print in this application, I get this exception:
enter image description here
Anyone have a suggestion as to what this issue might be. The only difference between this app and the other apps that run it is the htmlcontent. I checked for malformed html by replace the string with the htmlcontent from another working application, but it still fails.
Googled for a answer but didn't find anything.
I replaced the HTML content being sent with HTML content from a working application and it still failed.

It looks like I was looking in the wrong area. The page was using a  element, which was mucking it up. Once the  element was removed, worked fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
